# Update dynamic object (using QThread) image from C++ to QML

Tags: qml, qthread

I have a problem with my assignment.

After receiving data in real time, I can create and show **1** moving object image on a background from C++ to qml using ImageProvider (this is simple and done). However, my assignment requirements: "Click on button to generate dynamically a number of object moving **independently** (example 3 objects, but it should not be fixed). So I decided to create 3 threads for each item, each thread will be received data and update to image separately. However, my problem is:

In qml file, I must declare a code segment for update a image such:

```
Image  {
   id: id_image
   source: "image/MyImageProvider/id_image

   cache: false
   function reload(){
      source = "";
      source = "image/MyImageProvider/id_image"
}

Connections {
   target: MyObject
   onSignal_reload:{
     id_image.reload()
   }
}
```

How could I do the similar thing when I can not know number of object in advanced? Anyone have idea? Thanks.

Comment: What is *number of object* here?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `Image` Item into a `Repeater`.
Then subclass the `QAbstractItemModel` and use this as model for the Repeater.

Take a look at the example at
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html